# How to indicate safe links from post

Tags: hugo

I want to link a file using `file:///path/to/file` from a post, but the link disappears because of safety checks:

```
[my link](file:///path/to/file)
```

How can I allow this link on a post?

This case of use does not seem documented:

- [Links and Cross References | Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/cross-references/)
- [URL Management | Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/)
- [safeURL | Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/functions/safeurl/#readout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1 – overwrite the default link rendering

You can tell Goldmark (the renderer) how it should render links ([see docs](https://gohugo.io/templates/render-hooks/)), by creating a file in `layouts/_default/_markup/render-link.html`. This code should help, just make sure that it renders everything it should render in your case (see the mentioned docs what variables you can use in the file):

```html
<!-- layouts/_default/_markup/render-link.html -->
<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}">{{ .Text }}</a>
```

Note that the magic here is caused by the `safeURL` function ([documentation](https://gohugo.io/functions/safeurl/)). If you want to use the `safeURL` function only when the URL starts with `file://`, you can do something like this:

```html
<!-- layouts/_default/_markup/render-link.html -->
{{ if hasPrefix .Destination "file://" }}
    <a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}">{{ .Text }}</a>
{{ else }}
    <a href="{{ .Destination }}">{{ .Text }}</a>
{{ end }}
```

### Solution 2 – enable unsafe rendering in config (not recommended)

You can also enable rendering of all potentially unsafe links (and also HTML) everywhere by updating your configuration file (respectively the Goldmark renderer settings) like in the examples below. Search for an `unsafe` field in [this part of Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup#goldmark).

**You shouldn't use this unless it's the only acceptable solution for you. It enables rendering URLs like `javascript:unsafeFunction()` or HTML tags, which may not be what you want to allow.**

**TOML syntax (config.toml)**

```
[markup]
    [markup.goldmark]
        [markup.goldmark.renderer]
            unsafe = true
```

**YAML syntax (config.yml)**

```yaml
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: true
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. Disabling safety does not seem like a wise thing to do. **I like the link rendering solution**, but would specify prefixes to allow.

Comment: @xihh If you want to use safeHTML only when the link starts with **file://**, you can do this: `{{ if hasPrefix .Destination "file://" }}href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}"{{ else }}href="{{ .Destination }}"`, I'll also update my answer.

Comment: Add a comment  stating that unsafe rendering is not recommended and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @xihh I added it to the answer, hope it helps other developers to decide. Thanks for your recommendations!

Answer (score 1):

Solution using shortcodes

To solve the issue I [created a shortcode](https://gohugo.io/templates/shortcode-templates/) named `file_link.html`:

```
<a href="file://{{ .Get 1 | safeURL }}">{{ .Get 0 }}</a>
```

That way i can use on the body of the post:

```
{{< file_link "this text is shown" "/path/to/file" >}}
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
[this text is shown](file:///path/to/file )
```